# Can I overload the + operator on the decimal type?

Tags: c#, operator-overloading

There is a rounding error using the decimal because it reads another datatype from another system. So I was wondering if it is possible to overload the + operator on the decimal type? All the examples I see is on new defined structs.

Comment: Something in the back of my mind is nagging me saying "this is not the right approach". Can you clarify the statement "because it reads another datatype from another system"? Consider the possibility you will come to regret overloading +, especially if within its implementation you need to... add two decimals. Additionally, consider the possibility you're depending on a behavior that is specific to the .NET version/revision you're using today.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No `decimal` is a [value type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1ax56ch.aspx) and as such cannot be inherited. You would have to correct the rounding outside of this, perhaps via an extension method e.g.

```
public static decimal Add(this decimal value, ...)
{
    ... do manual calculation & rounding
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can only overload operators for a class/struct inside that class/struct's definition, so there's no way you can override the default `+` behaviour for the `decimal` type.

Ideally you'd write some kind of wrapper to correct the rounding error at source.